# Search first character of paragraph. If found, replace entire paragraph with bold

Tags: html

I need a command that will search for # sign in the first position of every paragraph in an rtf document.  If the # sign is found, I would like to be able to make the entire paragraph bold.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: HTML isn't a scripting language, so you can't do that with it. Please tag your question properly with the language you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with query.

JQUERY

```
$('p').each(function(){     
  if($(this).text().substr(0,1) == '#'){
     $(this).addClass('bold')
  }
})
```

CSS

```
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wcqW/3/

Comment: Doesn't that search for `#` signs in any position? The OP wanted the `#` signs only at the start of the paragraph. Also, your example looks like it works on HTML; the OP mentioned RTF.

Comment: Yes... I fixed it. I assumed since the question is tagged html that the OP wanted an HTML solution.

Comment: He could just open the document in Word and save it as a web page if he needs to add <p> tags to his .rtf document.